# Зачем делать telegram бота на Python через VDS если есть GoogleScript и Webhook?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, google-apps-script, vds, webhook

Имею опыт создания телеграмм ботов которые работают через вебхук, код пишется на гугл скрипте и + гугл таблицы используются как БД если боту нужно что ни будь хранить.

Хочу изучить Python, в том числе попробовать написать бота уже на нем, но как я понял используется некий vds сервер чтобы он работал 24/7, и как я понял они есть либо пробные версии либо платные.

Так вот вопрос, что такого может бот написанный на питоне, чего не может бот написанный на гугл скрипте? Можно ли бота на питоне тоже написать через вебхук? В чем преимущество vds?

Comment: GoogleScript требует знание жаваскрипта. Не все переваривают жаваскрипт. И если человек знает питон, то с чего вдруг ему изучать другой язык для написания софта. А если знаешь оба языка, то это уже упирается в баланс "удобство/функционал/стоимость". На своем хосте вы вольны выбирать что угодно и как угодно все это лепить. С GoogleScript  вы вынуждены использовать "что дают" - это может как устраивать, так и не устраивать. То есть очевидно, что питон дает полную свободу, но нужна ли она вам (и конечно он может вебхуки, да кто угодно может)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя дать хороший ответ на такой вопрос.

Основная проблема Apps Script в "платформозависимости" и низкой пропускной способности канала. Это связано с тем, что скрипты предполагают работу с сервисами Гугл, а не реализацию внешних сервисов, хотя, при малой нагрузке это реально. Пропускная способность по числу одновременных соединений также ограничена в целях безопасности.

Решение. Вы можете *не использовать VDS* и *использовать Таблицы*, при этом ***изучая Python***. Для этого просто опубликуйте своего бота как сервис в Container to production или как Cloud Function. Оба сервиса будут масштабироваться, потреблять в сотни раз меньше чем VDS. Продолжайте использовать Таблицы как базу данных, только помните, что общее число обращений к сервису Google Sheets без увеличения квот ограничено 100 запросами в секунду на проект. Ну, и Таблицы отвечают немного дольше, чем база данных в вашей сети. Это будет работать на хуках.

*Ответы типа "нравится - не нравится" для красавиц, которым придется терпеть и есть, что дадут.*